# Ruby define_method with parameter based on block

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I just figured it out, I updated my method to the below and passed the args to the block execution:

```
def self.element(element_name, options = {}, &block)
    define_method "#{element_name}" do |arg=nil|
        find self.instance_exec(*arg, &block), options
    end     
end
```

BINGOOOO!!!

My problem is the following -

I have a method that takes 3 parameters (method_name, options, &block) and this is how I put it together:

```
def self.element(element_name, options = {}, &block)
    define_method "#{element_name}" do
        find self.instance_exec(&block), options
    end     
end
```

this is how I call the method element:

```
element(:method_name, visible: 5)  { "#css path to my element" }
```

and now I use it anywhere I wish and perform any action I wish:

```
method_name.click
...
```

This has been working for me so far, but when I get into a situation where I have dynamic elements like the below example, I need to repeat the element finding (sometimes repeats itself to 20+ times):

```
{ "#csspath1" }
{ "#csspath2" }
{ "#csspath3" }
{ "#csspath4" }
...
```

I am passing the element path in block exactly to handle this situation, but haven't got there yet, what I would like to do is paramertize the repeatable numbers:

```
{ |arg| "#csspath#{arg}" }
```

and somehow have the method created using define_method pass the parameter inside my block, so the method would look like:

```
method(1).click
method(2).click
method(3).click
method(4).click
```

I haven't got there yet, any ideas would be welcome....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do? :

```
def element(element_name, options = {})
  define_method "#{element_name}" do |arg = nil|
    find yield(arg), options
  end     
end
```

Now define the method:

```
element(:method_name, visible: 5) {|num| "#csspath#{num}" }
```

Here `yield` statement executes the block with a default argument as `nil`, which will be `''`(empty string) while converting it into a string when you call:

```
method.click #=> will use "#csspath" for find
```

It will evaluate and use argument if passed like so:

```
method(1).click #=> will use "#csspath1" instead of "#csspath" for find
```

Comment: Ty so much, that works for me as well and looks even cleaner! any idea what is the difference between both solutions? yielding arguments or passing a block? passing a block is just a overhead for what I am trying to accomplish, that's about it?

Comment: Nothing much, except `instance_exec` always expect a block to be passed in the argument, however, above even `yield` won't work if you don't pass the block. But, you can prevent that behavior by saying `if block_given?` and raise an error if block is a must or just rescue without doing anything.